# Google Drive Script HTML Output

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs

I have a script running from a Google Drive Spreadsheet.  It takes data from a bunch of cells and creates a bunch of HTML code.  I need to put that code on an HTML document with a static link (the script will run multiple times and the HTML will be updated, but I need the link to be the same) that will be embedded in a website.

How can I write that code to an HTML file?  I know that you can create an HTML within a program in Google Scripts, but how could I write to that and then view it on the web?  If I was to use that document, how could I get a static public URL?  The only way I've figured out to use it is by deploying the web app, but requires someone to require into their google account to authorize the script to run.

Alternatively, if there is any way to extract the contents of a Google Document and write that to HTML, that would work as well, as that's where I have the HTML outputting to right now.

Any suggestions?  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There are two important things to consider here. First, you will have to host the HTML on a server, you can do this in Google Drive. You can read more documentation about this here:
https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en

Once you set up the Drive folder which will host your html, you can rely on the Google Drive class to look for your folder and create a file. You should get an idea by the following code:

```
function generateHtml(){
    // Get a list of the folders that match the Name parameter
    var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('Public Shared Folder');
    var publicSharedFolder = folders.next();

    //Get the HTML resource from where your Script and HTML file are located
    var htmlFileContent = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('NewHtml');

    // Create a new HTML file with the content from an existing HTML
    DriveApp.publicSharedFolder.createFile('New HTML File', htmlFileContent, MimeType.HTML);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  How can I open an existing HTML file by the ID and then edit that?

Comment: In that case, you can access the file via: var files = DriveApp.getFileById('itemId'); With that variable, you can use the following function: file.setContent('content'); I am not sure if you can read the content of the file, only overwrite it.